# Use jquery to remove <table></table> but keep the rows

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, tags

I'm generating several simple tables dynamically:

```
<table>
    <table><tr><td>aaa</td></td>bbb</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>xxxx</td></td>xxxx</td></tr></table>
</table>
```

I need to be able to strip the  tags from each inner table using jquery:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>aaa</td></td>bbb</td></tr>
    <tr><td>xxxx</td></td>xxxx</td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The HTML in the first example is completely invalid, and is not how it will be rendered in the browser. As such you can't fix this with JS. You need to correct the problem at the source, ie. where you generate the table HTML

Comment: Depending on the browser, the "outer" `table` will render as `<table></table>` *before* the two inner tables.  Therefore you have 3 sibling tables and not 1 with 2 children.  You *could* move them using something like `$("tr").appendTo($("table").first())` (add the `tbody` and append to that ofc) but, as above, better to fix properly.   If you add a question with how you generate it and what you want out, I'm sure someone will provide you with an answer quick enough.

Comment: Yep, I know it's not valid - which is why I'm trying to fix it.  The program that is generating the tables cannot be changed unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Was thinking there may be a way to assign the table to a string and then search replace the   tags with nothing

```
<table id="wrapperTable">
    <table><tr><td>aaa</td></td>bbb</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>xxxx</td></td>xxxx</td></tr></table>
</table>
```

jquery:

wrapperTable.Contents search/replace

I'm just not very familiar with JS or jquery - trying to make a temporary fix while we find new software